# svg is causing a height gap on my dom

Tags: jquery, html, svg, jquery-svg

What can I do to prevent this as I got a responsive layuot? at the moment the svg is causing a gap. can I make the `.target` getting the svg through jquery? if yes how?

**Html**

```
<style type="text/css">
  .target {
    mask: url(#m1);
  }
</style>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" >

<mask maskUnits="objectBoundingBox" maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" id="m1">
  <linearGradient  gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" id="g" x1="0" y1="0.86" x2="0" y2="0.99">
    <stop stop-color="white" offset="0"/>
    <stop stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0" offset="1"/>
  </linearGradient>
  <rect id="svg_1" height="1" width="1" y="0" x="0" stroke-width="0" fill="url(#g)" />
</mask>
</svg>
```

Comment: Can you create a demo jsfiddle to show what you mean by "gap"?

Comment: @BigBadaboom http://jsfiddle.net/Sqsn9/ thanks for looking into this. the <div class="hero-wrapper">
    <div class="hero"> should have the same height of the carousel !!!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Sqsn9/1/

Comment: I think you should be able to hide the SVG and still have the mask work.  That is: `<svg display="none">`.  Does that do what you want?

Comment: Setting width="0" and height="0" on the `<svg>` element would be better than display="none"